# PowerShell - show source computer on disconnected sessions

Tags: powershell

I've created a PS script that will list all servers in my Active Directory environment, check if a user is logged on and write it in a table (green for active session and red for a disconnected session).

I would like to add a portion where I can see the source ip or source computername where the rdp sessions originated from.

Why? Atm, we have +/- 200 servers and users are forgetting to log off or are closing the rdp session, leaving the user logged on and using resources. Since we user CyberArk (that uses shared users) there is no easy way to see who did it

Is there anyone that can help me out a bit?

Below, I've added the script that I'm using (I have shortened the function mailmessage, else it would not be properly readable)

```
###########################################################
$to = @("mailadres1@company.com")
###########################################################
#List all servers in domain 1
$Domain1 = Get-ADComputer -Filter { OperatingSystem -Like '*Windows*Server*' } -Properties OperatingSystem -Server DC1 | Select-Object name | Sort-Object Name
#List all servers in domain 2
$Domain2 = Get-ADComputer -Filter { OperatingSystem -Like '*Windows*Server*' } -Properties OperatingSystem -server DC2 | Select-Object name | Sort-Object Name
#Combine both lists
$servers = $Domain1 + $Domain2
#clear variables
$query = ""
$logged = ""
$x = ""
$empty= ""
$separator = " "
foreach($server in $servers)
    {
        $name = ($server.name).ToUpper()
                $test = ping $server.name -n 1
                if($test -like "*Ping request could not find host*" -or $test -like "*Request timed out.*" -or $test -like "*Destination host unreachable.*")
                    {
                        Write-Host "Pinging $name..." -ForegroundColor Red
                        $x += $name + "<br>"
                    }
                else
                    {
                        Write-Host "Pinging $name..." -ForegroundColor Green
                        $query = query user /server:$name
                        if($query -ne $null)
                            {
                                $logged += "<tr><th colspan='2'>" + $name + "</th></tr>"
                                #$logged += "<br>`n" + $name + "<br>`n"
                                foreach($line in $query) 
                                    {
                                        if($line -notlike " USERNAME              SESSIONNAME        ID  STATE   IDLE TIME  LOGON TIME")
                                            {
                                                $parts = $line -split '\s+'
                                                $username = $parts[1]
                                                if($parts[4] -eq "Active" -or $parts[4] -eq "Disc")
                                                    {
                                                        $state = $parts[4]
                                                        $date = $parts[6]
                                                        $time = $parts[7]
                                                    }
                                                else
                                                    {
                                                        $state = $parts[3]
                                                        $date = $parts[5]
                                                        $time = $parts[6]
                                                    }
                                                if($state -eq "Active"){ $logged += "<tr style='background-color: green; color: white'><td>$username</td><td>$state</td></tr>" } else { $logged += "<tr style='background-color: red; color: white'><td>$username</td><td>Disconnected (logged on since $date $time)</td></tr>" }
                                            }
                                    }
                            }
                    }
            
    }
$BodyText = @'
<html>
<body>
<span style='font-size:10.0pt;font-family:"Arial",sans-serif;'>
List of servers with loggedon users :<br><br>
<style>
TABLE{width:50%; border-width: 1px;border-style: solid;border-color: black;border-collapse: collapse; padding-right:5px}
TH{border-width: 1px;padding: 5px;border-style: solid;border-color: black; background-color: black; color: white}
TD{border-width: 1px;padding: 5px;border-style: solid;border-color: black}
<table>
@SERVERS
</table>
</style>
</span>
</font>
</body>
</html>
'@
$BodyText = $BodyText -replace "@SERVERS","$logged"
$Mailparam = @{
    BodyAsHtml = $true
    SmtpServer = 'smtpserver'
    From = "senderadress"
    To = $to
    Subject = "Logged accounts / server"
    Body = "$BodyText"
}

Send-MailMessage @Mailparam
```

Kind regards,
Dimi

Comment: First of all, don't name a self-defined function the same as an existing cmdlet. Furthermore, that function does absolutely nothing, since you close it immediately with a closing bracket: `function Send-MailMessage {}`

Comment: i've found it online and use it to add html. like i said, i removed it 'cause it's too big. you can ignore that part :)

Comment: I've removed the function from the original post.
now on to the actual question, adding the source computer's ip or computername :)